# Just an input in Python

Tags: python, input

I've just started learning Python. As this is my first language, don't be harsh on me if this is too easy. I can't figure out how to solve this. This is what i've programed:

```
a=input("Enter pyramid base size ")
H=input ("Enter pyramid height size ")
P=a*a+2*a*h
print (P)
```

But this comes out:

```
Enter pyramid base size 2
Enter pyramid height size 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\pyramid.py", line 3, in <module>
    P=a*a+2*a*h
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive so you need H instead of h: P=a*a+2*a*H

Comment: What are you trying to get for output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the input received is a string but for your equation, numbers are needed.
You can convert your input to an integer or float and then do the math

```
a = int(a)
h = float(h)
```

Now you might need to check if the input can be converted into a number and you can do something like:

```
try:
  h = int(h)
except ValueError:
  print 'the input couldnt be converted into an integer'
```

**Edit**

So, here is what your code should look like

```
a = input("Enter pyramid base size ")
h = input ("Enter pyramid height size ")

try:
  a = int(a)
  h = int(a)
  p = a*a + 2*a*h

  print (p)
except: ValueError:
  print 'Input cannot be converted to an integer'
```

Comment: Sorry if bothering you, but as I am new and started learning Python today, this is advanced for me, and I still can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs `a` and `b` are strings. While you can multiply a string by a number to repeat the string (for example, `'a' * 5 == 'aaaaa'`), you cannot multiply a string by a string.

If you want `P` to be a number, wrap your input calls in `int(input(...))`.